# File Encoding Format : ANSI_134_1968 and UTF : 8 Difference?

Tags: character-encoding

I would like to know what the difference is between File Encoding Format : ANSI_134_1968  and UTF : 8.

Comment: Simple: ANSI_134_1968 doesn't exist.

Comment: I've never heard of ANSI-134:1968, and can't find any reference to it, but assuming that's a year, it pre-dates Unicode (for which UTF-8 is a representation) by at least 20 years, so I doubt they have very much in common.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-existent encoding standards.

Comment: Presumably you mean ANSI X3.4-1968?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean [ANSI X3.4-1968](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#History), which is just a fancy name for ASCII:

The Unicode standard uses ASCII for its first 128 codepoints, so Unicode is a superset of ASCII.

UTF-8 is specially designed so that the first 128 codepoints take a single byte each, where the byte is identical to the one specified for ASCII.